# I want to print out dictionary json file content but i get an error string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

class Person is base class.

```
import json

class Person():
    """
    class Person
    """
    def __init__(self, name, ssn, home_address=""):
        """
        init method, constructor
        """
        self.name = name
        self._ssn = ssn
        self.home_address = home_address
    
# class teacher inherits from class teacher
# 
class Teacher(Person):
    """
    class Teacher
    """
    def __init__(self, name, ssn, home_address=""):
        """
        init method, constructor
        """
        super().__init__(name, ssn, home_address)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        """
        class method to read data from json file
        """
        #print(json_data)
        return cls(json_data["name"], json_data["ssn"], json_data["courses"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    teacher_json = json.load(open('teacher.json', encoding='utf-8'))
    teachers = []
    print(teacher_json)
    for k in teacher_json:
        #print(k)
        print(teachers.append(Teacher.from_json(k))
    print(teacher_json)
```

and json(teacher.json) file content:

```
{
    "name": "Steve",
    "ssn": "482075-3621",
    "courses": [
        "oopython",
        "oophp"
    ]
}
```

the teacher.json contains data to create and return a new instance of the class Teacher but when
I saw my code I noticed that my JSON file is a dictionary, and I am trying to print it out as a list
and I get this error `string indices must be integers` the result should be
like this:
Name: Steve SSN: 482075-3621 Courses: oopython, oophp

Comment: `teacher_json` is a single object, not a list of objects. Thus, `k` is successively `name`, `ssn`, and `courses`, not an object that has those keys.

Comment: Your file doesn't contain an array of objects, just a single object.

Comment: `teacher_json` is a dict so when you do `for k in teacher_json`, you're iterating over the keys (strings) of the dict. Then, you pass each key (`k`) to `Teacher.from_json(k)` where you basically try to access, e.g., `k["name"]` etc.

Comment: Your method `from_json()` would make sense if it takes JSON string and parse it inside the method (i.e. sort of utility function). Now you load JSON into dict outside the class, so you can instantiate it simply by `Teacher(**json_data)`. Note that `Teacher.__init__()` is missing `courses` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> this solve

```
import json

class Person():
    """
    class Person
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, ssn: str, home_address=[]):
        """
        init method, constructor
        """
        self.name = name
        self._ssn = ssn
        self.home_address = home_address
    
# class teacher inherits from class teacher
# 
class Teacher(Person):
    """
    class Teacher
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, ssn: str, home_address=[]):
        """
        init method, constructor
        """
        super().__init__(name, ssn, home_address)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        """
        class method to read data from json file
        """
        return cls(str(json_data["name"]), str(json_data["ssn"]), list(json_data["courses"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    teacher_json = json.load(open('teacher.json', encoding='utf-8'))
    teachers = []
    for k in teacher_json:
        teacher = Teacher.from_json(teacher_json)
        data = teachers.append(teacher)

    # print(teachers[0].name)
    print(teachers)
```

Comment: i tried you solution i get this: [<__main__.Teacher object at 0x035AB550>, <__main__.Teacher object at 0x035AB550>, <__main__.Teacher object at 0x035AB550>], instead of Name: Steve SSN: 482075-3621 Courses: oopython, oophp

Comment: yes, You can use it by index like ```teachers[0].name``` forget name from the object

Comment: skill i get this Name: Steve SSN: 482075-3621 Courses:  <class 'classes.Teacher'> instead of Name: Steve SSN: 482075-3621 Courses: oopython, oophp <class 'str'> and i have created another file which import them as so.     from teacher import Person, Teacher                                                                                                           asdf

Comment: ```                                                                                                               from teacher import Person, Teacher                                                                                                           with open(Teacher.file_name, "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
teachers = []

if data:
    for te in data:
        teacher = Teacher.from_json(data)
        teachers.append(teacher)

print(teachers)                                                                                                                          ```